# Open man pages in help window using terminal

Tags: command-line, manpage

While using **Gnome Do**, I discovered that man pages could also be opened in help window as shown in this image.
[image]

What is the command to open manuals in help through terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yelp` or `gnome-help`is the application you are looking for. These are part of system document browser. You can open manual pages in different window (as shown in the image in your question) from terminal as,

```
yelp man:command
```

or,

```
gnome-help man:command
```

For example, to get man page for `python` in different window.

```
yelp man:python
```

You can also open `file` and `info` also using `gnome-help`. <sup>[[source](http://linux.about.com/library/gnome/blgnome7n3d.htm)]</sup>

```
yelp file:///usr/share/gnome/help/gcalctool/C/gcalctool.xml
yelp info:make
```

Comment: one question.which default apps support showing manuals?

Comment: @adityapatil see the edit.